# Huffman Coding - Get Path to Leaf

Tags: java, binary-tree, huffman-code

I have my Huffman tree assembled, but now I need to display the path to a specified letter. The path needs to be displayed as 1's and 0's, where 1 is right child, and 0 is left child. If to get to a leaf from the root is right child, right child, left child, the path will be 110.

I am able to print each leaf, but I can't figure out out to get the path to each leaf. I am attempting to use a preOrder traversal method in my code.

```
import java.util.*;
```

import java.io.*;

public class assignment5 {

```
public static int nItems;
public static Node[] queueArray;
public static String path = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

      int A = 0;
      int B = 0;
      int C = 0;
      int D = 0;
      int E = 0;
      int F = 0;
      int G = 0;

      String fileName = "null";

         if(args.length > 0){    //checks for arguments, if any exists it assigns first one to be the file name

         fileName = args[0];

         }


      FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);

      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

      String line = reader.readLine();

      StringBuilder fileToString = new StringBuilder();

         while(line != null){

            fileToString.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();

         }

         fileToString.toString();
         reader.close();

         System.out.println(fileToString);
         System.out.println("\n\n");

      char[] letters = new char[fileToString.length()];

         for(int i = 0; i < fileToString.length(); i++)
            letters[i] = (fileToString.charAt(i));

         for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
            System.out.print(letters[i] + " ");

         for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){

            if(letters[i] == 'A')
               A++;
            else if(letters[i] == 'B')
               B++;
            else if(letters[i] == 'C')
               C++;
            else if(letters[i] == 'D')
               D++;
            else if(letters[i] == 'E')
               E++;
            else if(letters[i] == 'F')
               F++;
            else if(letters[i] == 'G')
               G++;
            else{}

         }

         System.out.println("\n\nLetter frequencies are as follows:\nA= " + A + "\nB= " + B + "\nC= " + C + "\nD= " + D + "\nE= " + E + "\nF= " + F + "\nG= " + G);

         Node node1 = new Node(A, 'A');
         Node node2 = new Node(B, 'B');
         Node node3 = new Node(C, 'C');
         Node node4 = new Node(D, 'D');
         Node node5 = new Node(E, 'E');
         Node node6 = new Node(F, 'F');
         Node node7 = new Node(G, 'G');

         priorityQueue pq = new priorityQueue(13);

         pq.insert(node1);
         pq.insert(node2);
         pq.insert(node3);
         pq.insert(node4);
         pq.insert(node5);
         pq.insert(node6);
         pq.insert(node7);

         while(nItems>1)
             pq.insert(pq.remove());


         pq.displayTree();


        pq.preOrder(queueArray[0], path);



}


public static class Node{

    public int iData;
    public char cData;
    public Node leftChild;
    public Node rightChild;

    public Node(int freq, char lett){

        iData = freq;
        cData = lett;
        leftChild = null;
        rightChild = null;

    }

}

public static class priorityQueue{


    public int maxSize;

    public priorityQueue(int size){

        maxSize = size;
        queueArray = new Node[maxSize];
        nItems = 0;

    }

    public void insert(Node newLink){

        int j;

        if(nItems==0)
            queueArray[nItems++]=newLink;
        else{

            for(j=nItems-1; j>=0; j--){

                if(newLink.iData > queueArray[j].iData)
                    queueArray[j+1] = queueArray[j];
                else
                    break;

            }

            queueArray[j+1] = newLink;
            nItems++;

        }

    }

    public void preOrder(Node localRoot, String code){

        path = path + code;

        if(localRoot != null){
            if(localRoot.cData != ' '){
            System.out.print(localRoot.cData + path + "\t");
            path = "";
            }
            preOrder(localRoot.leftChild, "0");

            preOrder(localRoot.rightChild, "1");

        }

    }


    public Node remove(){

        int freqs;

        freqs = queueArray[nItems-1].iData + queueArray[nItems-2].iData;


        Node newNode = new Node(freqs, ' ');

        if(queueArray[nItems-1].iData < queueArray[nItems-2].iData){
            newNode.leftChild = queueArray[nItems-1];
            newNode.rightChild = queueArray[nItems-2];
        }
        else{
            newNode.rightChild = queueArray[nItems-1];
            newNode.leftChild = queueArray[nItems-2];
        }           

        nItems-=2;


        return newNode;
    }

    public void displayQueue(){

        for(int i = 0; i<nItems; i++)
            System.out.print(queueArray[i].cData + ", " + queueArray[i].iData + " | ");

    }

    public void displayTree(){

        Node newNode = queueArray[0];

        Queue<Node> currentLevel = new LinkedList<Node>();
        Queue<Node> nextLevel = new LinkedList<Node>();

        currentLevel.add(newNode);

        while (!currentLevel.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<Node> iter = currentLevel.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Node currentNode = iter.next();
                if (currentNode.leftChild != null) {
                    nextLevel.add(currentNode.leftChild);
                }
                if (currentNode.rightChild != null) {
                    nextLevel.add(currentNode.rightChild);
                }
                System.out.print(currentNode.cData + " " + currentNode.iData + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            currentLevel = nextLevel;
            nextLevel = new LinkedList<Node>();

        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is the Node known which contains the specified letter or do you have to get it first?

Assuming you know the specific node. I would generally add a `Node parent;` field to your Node class. After that it's quite simple to follow the parent nodes until you reach the root and just record the path you took to get there.

Here is a simple example how it could be done:

```
private String getPathTo(Node node) {
    String path = "";
    Node parent = node.getParent();
    while(parent != null) {
        if(parent.getLeft().getData().compareTo(node.getData()) == 0) path = "0" + path;
        if(parent.getRight().getData().compareTo(node.getData()) == 0) path = "1" + path;
        node = parent;
        parent = node.getParent();
    }
    return path;
}
```

edit:
My key is a String here. Just for the sake of convenience.

```
private Node searchNode(Node root, String key) {
    Node result = null;
    LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(root);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node node = queue.poll();
        if(node.getData().compareTo(key) == 0) { result = node; }
        if(node.getLeft() != null) queue.add(node.getLeft());
        if(node.getRight() != null) queue.add(node.getRight());
    }
    return result;
}
```

This approach assumes that the keys are unique.

Comment: The node that contains a specified letter will be different for a different set of letters/frequencies. I am not sure if I can make a getParent() method that will find the parent node regardless of where the node is?

Comment: Since you are using a leftChild and rightChild field you could just set the parent simultaneously, while you are adding the specific child. No?

Comment: Ah, ok yes. I can get the parent nodes, but I wont know the node in which the specified key is located. Is there a way to start with the root, and cycle through the tree using leftChild, rightChild, and parent from the root?

Comment: @SammyWills Yes, that's what I asked at the beginning of my answer. You could just iterate through the tree using levelorder for example and return your specific node. Edited my answer for that, since code looks better there.